# Coverting roman numeral exceptions to decimal

Tags: java

For some class homework I need to create a program that converts roman numerals to decimal form. I can convert just fine as long as there are no exception characters such as IV or IX. How do I check for these exceptions? My attempt was to translate both the current character and the next one into decimal, then to compare them and if the next one (going right to left) is smaller to then subtract it. The problem is that I get out of bounds errors from this.

My current code is this:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String roman;
    int decimal = 0;
    int number = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter a Roman Numeral to convert to decimal form: ");

    roman = keyboard.next();
    roman = roman.toUpperCase();

    for (int count = roman.length()-1; count >= 0; count--)
    {
      char numeral = roman.charAt(count);
      switch (numeral){
        case 'I':
        decimal = 1;
        break;
        case 'V':
        decimal = 5;
        break;
        case 'X':
        decimal = 10;
        break;
        case 'L':
        decimal = 50;
        break;
        case 'C':
        decimal = 100;
        break;
        case 'D':
        decimal = 500;
        break;
        case 'M':
        decimal = 1000;
        break;
        default:
        System.out.println("Error: Invalid character detected.");
        break;
      }
      number = number + decimal;
    }

    System.out.println("The decimal equivalent is: " + number);
    System.out.println("Later!");
```

I'm still a beginner and most of the information I see on this kind of problem uses advanced solutions that I simply don't understand. I know I need to compare the characters but I'm not sure how to do this in a way that won't eventually go out of bounds.

EDIT: Solved! After posting the question I was struck by insight and solved the problem myself. This code works but I would appreciate any insights into how to improve it!

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String roman;
    int decimal = 0;
    int number = 0;
    int last = 0;

    System.out.println("This program converts Roman Numerals to decimal form.");
    System.out.println("Note: Roman Numerals are I, V, X, L, C, D and M.");
    System.out.println("All letters entered will be treated as capitalized.");
    System.out.print("Enter a Roman Numeral to convert to decimal form: ");

    roman = keyboard.next();
    roman = roman.toUpperCase();

    for (int count = roman.length()-1; count >= 0; count--)
    {
      char numeral = roman.charAt(count);
      switch (numeral){
        case 'I':
        decimal = 1;
        break;
        case 'V':
        decimal = 5;
        break;
        case 'X':
        decimal = 10;
        break;
        case 'L':
        decimal = 50;
        break;
        case 'C':
        decimal = 100;
        break;
        case 'D':
        decimal = 500;
        break;
        case 'M':
        decimal = 1000;
        break;
        default:
        System.out.println("Error: Invalid character detected.");
        System.exit(0); 
        break;
      }
      if (decimal >= last){
      number = number + decimal;
      }
      else {
      number = number - decimal;
      }
      last = decimal;
    }

    System.out.println("The decimal equivalent is: " + number);
    System.out.println("Later!");
```

Comment: Your posted code does not seem to have any problems.

Comment: The problem is that for an entry if IV it will print 6 rather than 4 as it will add I and V instead of subtracting I from V. I've solved it just now however and I'll post the solution shortly for those in the same boat.

Comment: You should post your working code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a decimal is `##.##`, and an integer is `##`, so you should probably change `demical` to `num`.

Set the number as you already do, and add a check after it for the exception character. But first ensure that it exists:

```
if(this character is not the first  &&  the previous character is an exception)
   adjust the number as necessary
```

This will avoid an out-of-bounds exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Do you think it is more or less useful than the one I went with in the edit of my original post?

Comment: Your implementation is better and more elegant than I suggested. With your way there's no need to check `(current character - 1)` at all, because your *current* character is the previous to the *one read in before it*. It avoids the whole possibility of an index-out-of-bounds exception. Smart.

Comment: I just upvoted your question, and I'll upvote your answer, too, when you post it.

Comment: Thank you! I need more reputation to post an answer sooner than 8 hours but I'll update it then for future troubled students.